# what is the suitable projection coordinate system for Iran

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, coordinates, iran

I am doing analysis for province wise Iran. I am using WGS1984 as my geographical coordinate system, and I do not know which is suitable Projection coordinate system for entire Iran.

I feel the UTM will not be suitable because the country shares several zones in UTM system.

Comment: What are your objectives (e.g. measuring distance or area, cartographic effect, etc)?

Comment: I want to measure the area and length

Comment: Do you have the flexibility to create a custom Albers or Lambert equal-area projection, or are you limited to pre-defined SRIDs?

Comment: i am using ArcGIS, i have few knowledge about projection. what i have to do

Comment: Good question. Do you need to measure distances? If not WGS84 might be ok.

Answer (score 2):

[GeoRepository](http://georepository.com/search/map) is a great resource for discovering coordinate systems.

[Here](http://georepository.com/search/by-location/?lat=32.7691&lon=54.7778&submit=Search+Database&Selected+Location=Selected+Location&OpenLayers_Control_LayerSwitcher_4_baseLayers=Hybrid) is a list of possible Projections, but I would suggest you don't take my word for it, I'm not very familiar with that area.

- Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer - just found some info - there is a [Foreign Maps (Google eBook)](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ybAXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=native%20Iran%20coordinate%20system&source=bl&ots=WqYmLWGqeV&sig=w-iqp4uQo60HJo4Y-tm--xXoGfs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZESeUonmM-GqyAGAhYHYCg&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=native%20Iran%20coordinate%20system&f=false) available online that describes the various coordinate systems used in the middle east including Iran.

Here is a capture of the section that discusses the Iranian Coordinate Systems:

[image]

WGS1984 is probably suitable. If you need to measure distances, you could convert or use some tools or re-project the map as larger scales to either of the 4 UTM zones, although splitting it to the 2 main zones 39 and 40 would probably be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=iran which provides some useful info about projections for different area/regions across the globe might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

you should use labmbert or GCS WGS 1984 for entire Iran . These are the coordinate systems that use in Iran . NCC (www.ncc.org.ir) uses Lambert for Iran . If you work in a province then best option is UTM . If the province is located in two UTM Zone you should use GCS WGS 1984

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with provinces, you could assume that these are within a specified UTM zone. You could add a UTM zone-grid, extract the UTM zone per province, and then repeat the analysis for each province separately, or calculate the values required with the required UTM zone.

If you really want to use a projection for the whole of Iran, then you would be looking for a lambertian projection. I used once the EPSG:6931 which is a projected grid system (EASE-Grid projections) developed recently in a version 2.0 by Brodzik et al. 2014. https://doi.org/10.3390/ijgi1010032

I hope this helps!